# How to prevent use of `w` and `who` on shared webhosts

Tags: linux, shared-hosting

We are in the process of setting up a hosting machine that clients will have SSH access to. We don't want them to be able to see a list of user accounts, but the problem we have run into are commands like `w` and `who`.

We could disable those, but then they could just bring their own binary. I just tried on a shared webhost, and I was the only user who showed up in `w`, even though it's a large shared box and I doubt I'm the only one on.

How can I prevent users from seeing who else has logged in via SSH?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`w` and `who` basically read the data from `/var/run/utmp`. If you change the permissions of it to say 660 that will prevent users being able to read it.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the command by running `chmod 700 /usr/bin/who`. I'd do this in addition to Mlfe's answer.

This will disable execution for all users except root.

Comment: My understanding is that just making `/user/bin/who` unexecutable is insufficient because a user could simply bring another `who` binary and run it from their home directory.

Comment: It is, I just said use it in addition :)